# How to detect that whole image was downloaded in Android

Tags: java, android

I download images into my android application with this code:

```
private void download(URL url, File file) throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "download(): downloading file: " + url);

    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bufferStream;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        bufferStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream, 512);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        int current;
        while ((current = bufferStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, current);
        }
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but some users and testers complained about incomplete photos. I suspect small network lags which interrupt connection. 
So I would like to detect if whole image was downloaded and saved file is complete image. Is there any way how to detect file size from BufferedInputStream or is there another way how detect download completion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using [Google Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) which provides a super simple interface for networking in general, and image loading specifically. It takes care of threading and batching for you.

It's what Google use on the Google Play app.

It will solve your problem by providing listeners that notify you when the job is complete.

Comment: Great answer, thank you, it requires refactor of my application. I will definitely do it in few months. But now I try some simple solution.

Comment: I totally understand. Refacotring Volley in might take a bit of work, but not a lot, and it's completely worth in my experience. It could save you a whole bunch of work down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/). I think it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading an ordinary file over HTTP, the method [getContentLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) of URLConnection gives you the length that the file should have in the end.

You can compare the returned value of this method to the file length/length of downloaded data. If it's equal, then the file is complete:

```
int contentLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();
if (contentLength != -1) {
    if (contentLength == file.length()) {
        System.out.println("file is complete");
    } else {
        System.out.println("file is incomplete");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("unknown if file is complete");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the second condition is allwas false. For example: contentLength is 1499 but file.length() returns 1627.